# Get text inside xml tag using grep

Tags: regex, bash, tags, grep

It's Friday afternoon, and my brain has frozen!

```
grep -E -m 1 -o "<title>(.*)</title>" myfile.rss
```

returns

```
<title>Some title</title>
```

How do I just get `Some title`?

Comment: Bash don't have a build-in function to parse XML. You can consider to use PHP, perl to parse XML in proper manner. Then getting the node value will be easy

Comment: Nah, that's complete overkill for the task!

Comment: For what I understand we only want to extract title content from xml of known layout, not parse xml. For parsing xml `xmlstarlet` may be useful utility.

Comment: There is not perfect way for XML parsing using pure bash commands.

Comment: The point is that the OP doesn't need a perfect way. And not talking about bash builtins either. `grep` is no bash builtin.

Comment: Quite right @Michael, all I needed was to pull out one tag from the XML to generate filenames in a script. It's working now!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

pipe it further through, for instance

```
sed -e 's,.*<title>\([^<]*\)</title>.*,\1,g'
```

Comment: Thanks! Brain thawing out ;-)

Comment: +1, but note that using `sed` to parse XML (or HTML) isn't generally a good idea. It should be done only when the input is well known and doesn't vary unexpectedly. For anything slurped automatically from the internet a proper parser should be used.

Comment: @Sorpigal, I agree completely, see comments to the question itself for details.