# Command line argument not recognised after pipe

Tags: xml-parsing, grep

I did post this question to a thread from 2011 ([Get text inside xml tag using grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270922/get-text-inside-xml-tag-using-grep/18570225#18570225)). I did try to get the final answer to work using commandline arguments ($1=filname, $2=tagname) instead of the fixed names:

```
grep -E -m 1 -o "<$2>(.*)</$2>" ./private/$1.xml | sed -e 's,.*<$2>\([^<]*\)</$2>.*,\1,g'
```

Apparantly this does not work, because the part after the pipe doesn't get the argument $2.
I am a total linux noob, but my hunch is that the pipe starts a new process that does not get the parent arguments. I tried Google for quite some time, but do get more confused.
Is there a simple work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your command does not work because variables in '-quotes are not replaced.

This should work:

```
grep -E -m 1 -o "<$2>(.*)</$2>" ./private/$1.xml | sed -e "s,.*<$2>\\([^<]*\\)</$2>.*,\\1,g"
```

That said, using grep for such an task it not really a good idea. It is better to use an actual html processor like my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) (or xpath/xmlstarlet/... ). Then you can just write:

```
xidel ./private/$1.xml -e //$2
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I fully agree, his is indeed a bad idea, but I am awaiting a proper XML parser in the software package I use. I 'll have a look at Xidel